# How to make javascript alarm to be played 100%?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<span id="countdown"></span>
<script>
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML =
  0 + ":" + 10;
startTimer();

function startTimer() {
  var bell = new Audio('http://soundbible.com/mp3/Store_Door_Chime-Mike_Koenig-570742973.mp3');
  var presentTime = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML;
  var timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
  var m = timeArray[0];
  var s = checkSecond((timeArray[1] - 1));
  if(s==59){m=m-1}
  if((m==0) && (s==1)){bell.play();}
  if(m<0){document.getElementById('countdown').style.display = "none"; 
      Timer.stop();}

  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = m + ":" + s;
  setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
}

function checkSecond(sec) {
  if (sec < 10 && sec >= 0) {sec = "0" + sec}; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  if (sec < 0) {sec = "59"};
  return sec;
}
</script>
```

The code is for my 15 minutes of meditation right after turn of my PC with other scripts, I placed this countdown code to most bottom of the html file and additionally the other codes are for display local time, list of daily todo and countup timer, and I'm keeping the html file on local storage & opening with chrome.

As I've tested, the code is not play the mp3 properly sometimes.
I guess it happens when the mp3 is not stored on cashed on local storage, but seem like it's not the matter of the internet speed though, even after 15 minutes of meditation it didn't play the bell, it's three days of row every morning until today, so I couldn't concentrate solidly to check whether the time is up or not.
Also as I've tested, it happens even the mp3 is located on my PC local storage.

The weird part is when I try the code on Tryit editor in both of case; [only with the countdown script](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FTMXTCXHI0KM) & [entire scripts of my todo list thing](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FTMXX43M73T7), both works fine, it's playing the bell 100% as so far as I tested.

So I'd consider to move the entire code on my personal blog,
[seem like only with the above code works as it's light one on my blog](http://ndaesik.tistory.com/),

[but the entire code is sometimes work and sometimes are not on my blog](http://pearlearrings.tistory.com/).

If it's play 0% then it could be easier to manage or least easier to ask for get help, but I have no idea how to handle this and even I don't know how to ask for get help for it.

Is their a way to check files are played? so reload it when it fails I guess?
or is this just a matter of mismanaging of the code?

Help would be really grateful, Thanks.

Comment: I didn't check and measures all the times, but As I checked again, on the blog the fully scripted page it plays like 80% of chance. but In the local file, the matter is worse feel like below than 50% to play the external mp3. :0

Comment: Try preloading the audio in a variable first: `var myAudio = new Audio([the url]);` Then, when the condition is met, `myAudio.play();`

Comment: Thanks Louys!, I'll try right on the way!

Comment: i've changed the code to preload the mp3, but still having same issue though :0,
I'll paste the edited code on my post.

Comment: I tried to make the code to onloaded with body element to solve, but it didn't work, I'd rather try get another upcount script from somewhere and put alarm on it later. btw thanks for Louys for trying to help :)

Comment: Strangely... I also have problem with this. I have improved your counter a bit on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KBvgXN?editors=1011)... But the issue really is about the audio. I don't know why... It is loaded by the browser... Partially... But it should play. I'm scratching my head.

Comment: Crap... I found it. The user has to interact with the document before the `play()`. Look at this [codepen v2](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qyXqLO?editors=1011) there is is big long error message... But if you click anywhere in the document before the counter hits zero... The sound plays. I will edit a nicely documented answer.

Comment: Wow, why the hell..? I'll gonna test for all my links above now, thanks for help !

Comment: Yeah Indeed, you are correct, I don't know how to solve this problem but least I will can be concentrate on my meditation by hit the browser before I go deep inside my mind.

Comment: It's streaked by google policy and seem like no way to escape. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes , I really appreciate for your help, Louys! I don't know the value of some credits on this site but you deserve to take upvote by posting your answer if you want !

Comment: Aha, users can change their settings via go "chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy" then change set "no user gesture is required" I've done and it works smoothly without hit the elements, thanks a bunch !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It strangely took a lot of time before I find this simple issue.

I was aware that a web page can not programmatically play an audio file on a mobile device without *user gesture*. But I tought it was not the case on desktop.

Well, it's not the same restriction, but there is one!

The audio play does not require a direct button click to trigger the `.play()`... But the user has to at least *«interact with the document»*. Be it just a click in the body!

And that was why my tests on your countdown were all failing... It did not need to click within the 10 seconds countdown.

After a quick read of [this Google Updates article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise), dated march 2016 (!), I tried to console log an error. That was in Codepen... So in an `iframe`! [See here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/rrzjVB?editors=0011)

> play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

If the user click anywhere in the document, the play **will** work.
So I added you a button as a reminder.

I also improved your countdown timer a bit... Feel free to ask questions about it.
here is your code:

```js
document.getElementById('atLeastOneClick').addEventListener("click",function(){
  this.innerHTML="Ok for meditation.";
});


document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 0 + ":" + 10;

var bell = new Audio('http://soundbible.com/mp3/Store_Door_Chime-Mike_Koenig-570742973.mp3');

var timer_interval;
timer_interval = setInterval(Timer, 1000);

function Timer() {
  var presentTime = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML;
  var timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
  var m = parseInt(timeArray[0]);
  var s = parseInt(timeArray[1]);

  s--;

  if(s<0){
    m--;
    s=59;
  }
  if(m<0){
    m=0;
    s=0;
    console.log("Timer ended.");
    bell.play();
    clearInterval(timer_interval);
  }

  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = m + ":" + checkSecond(s);
}

function checkSecond(sec) {
  if (sec < 10 && sec >= 0) {sec = "0" + sec}; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return sec;
}
```

```html
<button id="atLeastOneClick">Click me one time!</button><br>
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/pZrRgB)

Comment: May I have a another question ?

I've tried to put 0 if the minutes are less than ten,
so I copied the last part of the second, and tried to make the version of two digits of minutes . something like below, 

I didn't tested yet the below one that I just wrote, but I keep failed to make the one, that i've tried was keep display 0 most front of the text every second; 
00:10 -> 000:09 -> 0000:08

function checkMInutes(min) {
  if (min < 10 && min >= 0) {min = "0" + min}; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return min;
}

Comment: Yes sure go for it!

Comment: I just edited the comment, I'm just a newb of javascript, the answer could be make me help to understand the logic by comparison of right one and wrong one.

Comment: When you add a zero(`"0"`) in front of an integer... It becomes a string. So always `parseInt(min)` before the comparison and before the add zero. ;) In fact... you should do `min = parseInt(min); checkMInutes(min);` That is why is used your `checkSecond()` only in the `.innerHTML`.

Comment: ParseInt, aha, I see, I think I could be handle myself this time, thanks again, it's always feel so cool after solve a matter by matter, I understand the feel why so many peoples are saying themselves as code addicted, I'll might become one of them!

Comment: thanks for all the help, hope you have a awesome day!

Comment: You too... Have a nice meditation... You'll need it if you're to become code addict ;D