# How does YouTube work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, html5-video, autoplay

Google Chrome doesn't respect the `autoplay` attribute on HTML5 `<video>` elements. Using `video.play()` JavaScript as soon as the page loads throws an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

OK, but YouTube videos are HTML5 and they autoplay just fine. **What technique does YouTube use to bypass Chrome's restriction?** Are all webpages able to do the same (or no, maybe because YouTube has an exception since Google owns it)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make javascript alarm to be played 100%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529440/how-to-make-javascript-alarm-to-be-played-100)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette No, I am asking specifically about the JavaScript that YouTube uses to autoplay videos.

Comment: I marked as duplicate because I answered to a similar question already. [**This Google article**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise) hold all the information you seek. It's a browser limitation... Nothing to do with Youtube.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yeah but what exactly does YouTube do in the `Promise` to bypass this browser limitation?

Comment: Youtube is owned by Google... I suppose they made an exception... The user definitely wants to see a video, which is not obvious on other sites.

Comment: This said... As in the suggested duplicate, you just have to trigger the play on any `body` click. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Youtube, it is probably a pre-populated white list

https://blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/

> If you don’t have browsing history, Chrome allows autoplay for over 1,000 sites where we see that the highest percentage of visitors play media with sound.

---

For other cases, you can refer to the following rules (for Chrome at least)

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

> Autoplay with sound is allowed if:
>
> User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
>
> On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning the user has previously played video with sound.